# Appending searching instructions when opening a browser from the terminal

Tags: command-line, internet, browser

I open my browser with the following command:

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop
```

But based on output received from executing another command, I want to basically append search engine addresses and search terms that is executed upon opening the browser. I think this could probably be done somehow by making additions to the command above, but again I really have no idea what I'm talking about here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Tor Browser pretty much like any Firefox from the command line. For all the options type

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop --help
```

For example to pass it a URL to open on startup, type

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop www.duckduckgo.com
```

You can also define a default search engine and pass it a search term using the --search option.

Edit: The same works with plain Firefox of course.

Comment: ok well this suits me even better if I can look at everything happening from inside the terminal I might actually learn something for a change.I just assumed it would be possible because I could never find a command line based browser for windows 10, so I just thought that was a thing that's not allowed, I originally wanted to just learn about how the internet works from within the maple interface, and yes it has relevant packages but functionality is so limited it became a waste of time